# Is it possible to set compnent.id in angular?

Tags: angular

Like angular have App_id (https://angular.io/api/core/APP_ID) to control application id for Emulated style generation,

_nghost-**test**-**c12**

Using [{ provide: APP_ID, useValue: 'test' }], middle value can be updated to "test",

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NoEncapsulationComponent,
    ShadowDomEncapsulationComponent,
    EmulatedEncapsulationComponent,
  ],
  imports: [BrowserModule],
  providers: [{ provide: APP_ID, useValue: 'test' }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
```

Is it possible to set the compnentid (-**c12**) too ?

Comment: Possibly XY problem. Why do you want that?

Comment: ^- No but why ??

Comment: we have automation to validate the html, and everytime upgrading angular fails the previous angular version regex.
For example in 14 - it is _nghost-test-c12 where as in angular 16  it become _nghost-test-c11232, and the automation fails to validate the rendered html... 
So if we can customize this.. we will have control on ids

Comment: @Clashsoft -I agree. . . lemme look at alternative... :) I thought may be for app angular provides. .. so for component there may be an "id" field exposed to be set which i may not aware of ...